# PHP Open PDF file in adobe reader

Tags: php, html

I Have alot of PDF files saved on the network drive. All the pdf files are linked to a task. I want to open them in reader instead of downloading it or open in a chrome tab.

I get the right PDF files with the right task using this:

```
echo "<b>Documenten: </b><br>"; 
    $documentenwo = "SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT INNER JOIN DOCUMENT_REF_WO ON DOCUMENT.ID = DOCUMENT_REF_WO.DOCUMENT_ID WHERE DOCUMENT_REF_WO.WORKORDER_BASE_ID='".$base."' AND DOCUMENT_REF_WO.WORKORDER_LOT_ID='".$lot."' AND DOCUMENT_REF_WO.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID='".$split."' AND ID NOT LIKE '%.stp' AND ID NOT LIKE '%.dxf'";   
    $STH = $pdo->prepare($documentenwo);
    $STH->execute();
    while($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        $file_patch = $row["DOC_FILE_PATH"];
        if(!empty(trim($file_patch))){
            $file_patch = trim($file_patch);
            $file_patch = str_replace("M:", "file://local/data", $file_patch);
        }
        $id = $row["ID"];
        $path = $file_patch."/".$id;   
        echo "<p><a href=".$file_patch."/".$id." target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-download'></i> ".$row["ID"]."</a></p>";          
    }
```

When I open a pdf file, It will be openend in chrome pdf viewer.

I want to open it in adobe reader from its original location. Not download it. Just open the file from it's original location.

Why?

When someone have a remark in 1 of the documents, it will be saved at its original location, so everyone else can see his remark inside the pdf file.

Comment: that's a preference the user must set in their Browser preferences, you can't force the browser to ignore the user's settings

Comment: @Sfili_81 that is no problem. I already tried some things on the user computers, but no result so far. All users use google chrome

Comment: You can't directly control these file handling settings because that would be a security vulnerability.  Instead, a better UX option is to provide step-by-step guidance to users showing screenshots of their browser and how to download and open the file in Adobe Reader.

Comment: @NRohler Ah ok. Not the answer I was expecting for, but I have to accept it haha. Thanks!

Comment: "Not download it. Just open the file from it's original location." ...this is nonsensical. In order to view a file on a computer the file content must be copied from the remote server and loaded into the computer's memory. So even if the PDF ends up displayed in an inline PDF viewer within Chrome, the file has already been downloaded. After all, on which computer does Chrome run - the server or the user's computer? If the user then chooses to save the file permanently, it just moves from the temp folder to the folder they select, there is no more downloading.

Comment: As others have pointed out, in a web browser context you can't force the user to open the file in any particular viewer, it's entirely up to them and their settings. if you were downloading the files via a HTTP server (instead of `file://`) and using PHP to control the download, you could set headers which encourage the browser to download the file to disk rather than displaying it in an inline viewer but a) it's only guidance and b) the user then still has to click on the file to open it.

Comment: To be clear, This is sort of a PHP school project for an inside network. So every computers is connected to the same network and shared folders. everybody have acces to the M: drive for example. The M drive has 10 TB data so by clicking the link, it will be way more faster than searching for the right pdf file.  @ADyson

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, although I'm not entirely sure how it's related to any of the points I made or why you are telling me - perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: I'm telling you this because you said this: "this is nonsensical. In order to view a file on a computer the file content must be copied from the remote server and loaded into the computer's memory." The files are already there on the computers, so the users don't have to download them...

Comment: "The files are already there on the computers"...no, they're on network drives, as you said yourself. even if you opened the file directly using Windows Explorer, the content would still be copied across the network into the local computer's memory, otherwise no application could display it. The same applies if you're using a browser to view it. The main difference is that because of the browser context, it does actually create a copy of the file on the disk (either in the temp file or on the user's local disk) - because that's how browsers work, they expect to use HTTP normally, not file://

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks. any idea if it can work by execute a batch? like: shell_exec('start "" "C:\\Users\\4700\\Downloads\\test.pdf"'); using this won't work xD

Comment: That would open it on the webserver, not on the client

Answer (score 1):

I've been in your same situation with an intranet php webapp. Users didn't want to view pdf's from network server in browser tab they wanted to edit it directly in Acrobat Pro.
Of course you have two barriers, php is server based and javascript is not allowed to run programs in the client machine.
After thinking and thinking I've found a workaround, ajax will request a php script that will compose a batch file to open the acrobat pro with the file (network path) as parameter. So after warnings of dangerous type of file you download a .cmd and when executed it will open the file in the program that you wanted.
If you want to use other program than the default one just add the path to the program executable.
And it is self destructable so you won't have a lot of .cmd's in your download folder.

File called acrobat.php?filename=path_to_the_file (web path)

```
<?php 
extract($_REQUEST);
$filename = realpath($filename);
$filename = str_replace("D:\\Pdf_folder\\","\\\\Server_name\\Pdf_folder\\",$filename); //replace internal server path to network path
function acrobat($filename) {
   header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=acrobat.cmd");
print $filename; //dowload file called acrobat.cmd
}
//call the function with the command to open pdf by default program.
 acrobat( "start \"\" \"$filename\" ".PHP_EOL." DEL \"%~f0\"");
```